# What device types/traits should I use for a Heat Pump?

Tags: actions-on-google

Trying to find the most suitable type/trait for a heat pump (for those who don't know, a heat pump uses the same technology as an AC unit but is primarily used for heating, can also be used for cooling)

An action.devices.types.AC_UNIT (https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/guides/airconditioning) specifically says it's not for heating, while a action.devices.types.THERMOSTAT (https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/guides/thermostat) says it's different to heaters and AC units.

The action.devices.traits.TemperatureControl and action.devices.traits.TemperatureSetting both seem relevant to a heat pump also.  The language for each seems awkward, eg "set the heatpump to heat" works for TemperatureControl but only has limited options (heat, cool, "heatcool" - not custom modes like "auto" or "fan") but that same command does not for TemperatureSetting (even with the Modes trait set).  The TemperatureControl doesn't handle the state of the device being off (from the OnOff trait), but only works if the thermostatMode is "off" instead.  The voice command "what is the indoor temperature" also doesn't work with the TemperatureSetting trait.

My current thinking is that I need to implement both TemperatureControl and TemperatureSetting traits (not sure how to deal with the conflicting 'off' states) and that the device type is just for an icon so I should just pick the Thermostat type. Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A smart home device can have one type but several traits. In your case, it probably makes sense to use the `AC_UNIT` type since it's similar.

You have several options for the traits you want to support. If you want, you can use the **[TemperatureSetting](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/temperaturesetting)** trait. This would be similar to a thermostat, and give you the ability to set modes like *off*, *heat*, and *cool*. You can also give it a *setpoint* and *ambient temperature*. This probably makes the most sense for your case.

Alternatively you can use the more generic **[TemperatureControl](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/temperaturecontrol)** trait. This would allow you to give it direct temperatures to be set to, which would may not make sense for what you want.

If you are looking for additional modes, you can use the **[Modes](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/modes)** trait. This will allow you to use custom modes which will work alongside the modes that come with the **TemperatureSetting** trait.

There is also the generic **[OnOff](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/onoff)** trait if you just want a simple switching functionality.

You can take a look at [the full list of traits](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/) and see which one or which ones are most suitable for your devices.

```
{
  "availableModes": [{
  "name": "mode",
  "name_values": [{
    "name_synonym": ["mode"],
    "lang": "en"
  }],
  "settings": [{
    "setting_name": "Wind",
    "setting_values": [{
      "setting_synonym": ["wind", "fan"],
      "lang": "en"
    }]
  },
  {
    "setting_name": "Auto",
    "setting_values": [{
      "setting_synonym": ["auto", "automatic"],
      "lang": "en"
    }]
  }],
  "ordered": false
 }]
}
```

Comment: The OnOff trait seems to conflict with the TemperatureSetting trait, when the device is off from OnOff, the assistant says the device is unreachable.  Will try with the Modes trait to see how the assistant handles additional modes to TemperatureSetting, but at first glance "set the heatpump to auto 21 degrees" wont work as well as "set the heatpump to heat 21 degrees"

Comment: Setting the mode is different than setting the setpoint. You can "set the heatpump to auto and set the heatpump to 21 degrees".

Comment: TemperatureSetting seems to trump any Modes, for example "set the heat pump to auto" gives a response of "That mode isn't available for the Heat Pump".  It also seems to prevent any fan speeds from being set.

Comment: Can you share what your sync response looks like?